# what is the equivalent of fs2.Scheduler in fs2 (0.10.x) in newer versions

Tags: scala, scala-cats, fs2, cats-effect

I'm migrating fs2 0.10.x version to version 1.0.0.

Our code uses [`fs2.Scheduler`](https://github.com/functional-streams-for-scala/fs2/blob/series/0.10/core/shared/src/main/scala/fs2/Scheduler.scala) in from fs2 version 0.10.x.

I don't know what is the equivalent in newer fs2 version 1.0.0.

I went through the migration guide [here](https://github.com/functional-streams-for-scala/fs2/blob/series/0.10/docs/migration-guide-0.10.md) but couldn't find the migration guidelines for 0.10.x to 1.0.0 or anything similar.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need the [migration guide ***from*** 0.10 to 1.0](https://github.com/functional-streams-for-scala/fs2/blob/series/1.0/docs/migration-guide-1.0.md) rather than ***to*** 0.10 that you pointed to. The relevant section says:

> The new `cats.effect.Timer` type was introduced in cats-effect 0.10. This type provides much of the same functionality as the `fs2.Scheduler` type with the added functionality of supporting cancelation of sleeps. Hence, `fs2.Scheduler` has been removed and all of the stream-specific methods have been moved to the `fs2.Stream` companion. A `Timer[IO]` instance is available implicitly for both the JVM and Scala.js, meaning there's no need to allocate and shutdown a timer. Timer instances for other effect types can either be defined manually or derived from the `Timer[IO]` instance via `Timer.derive[F]`.

and then there is also a table for specific examples of what mapped where.